# ASP.NET can't recognize the button although it has an ID

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple code taken from my friend.

I added the html and the code behind.

In the markup I have this:

```
<asp:Button ID="BtnSaveCallerInfo" runat="server" 
            onclick="BtnSaveCallerInfo_Click" 
            style="background-color: #640064; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: 700;" Text="Save" Width="64px" />
```

In the page load, I tried to do this:

```
BtnSaveCallerInfo.Visible = false;
```

but I get this error:

> The name 'BtnSaveCallerInfo' does not exist in the current context
>   C:\Users\User\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\TestC1\TestC1\Test.aspx.cs

Help please

Comment: but it compiles?  I would remove it and add it again...

Comment: Is it in a repeater ?

Comment: Is it in a data-bound context, such as in a `GridView` or `Repeater`?

Comment: `I added the html`.  Should we assume that by "html" you mean "aspx"?

Comment: sometimes copy/paste is problematic.  the designer needs you to manually the control so it can properly create the .designer.cs code.

Comment: What does the first line of your aspx page look like? Does it match the class name of wherever you're trying to access the button?

Comment: @TMcKeown i actually created a completely new project and added it myself

Comment: @patrickinmpls no it is in td in tr in table

Comment: @JonathanLonowski it is in td in tr in table.

Comment: is this the only control?  why don't you paste the entire .aspx html

Comment: @McGarnagle i mean the code of the html. yes the aspx

Comment: @itsme86 the first line in my aspx is `<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestC1.Test" %>
<%@ Register assembly="eWorld.UI, Version=2.0.6.2393, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24d65337282035f2" namespace="eWorld.UI" tagprefix="ew" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>` and the code behind is in Test.aspx.cs

Comment: @TMcKeown I am actually doing that. i pasted the whole code. and i got a lot of errors, all about controllers are not recoginzed, so i thought that i will ask about one and if i solve it. the whole other errors will be solved easly

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli The real question though, is does that match the namespace and filename of wherever you're trying to access the button? If not, you'll need to fix that.

Comment: @itsme86 the `Test.aspx.cs` files contains `public partial class Test` in this name space `namespace TestC1` and the `Test.aspx.designer.cs` contains `public partial class CallInfo` without namespace

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using web forms.  If that's the case: the `BtnSaveCallerInfo` control is probably not in your designer.cs or designer.vb file.  That file could be corrupted.  See [here](http://www.undermyhat.org/blog/2009/07/tip-regenerate-aspx-designer-cs-files-when-corrupted/) to regenerate the file - then you should be good.

Comment: I checked the Test.aspx.designer.cs file and I see that the class name is `caller` while my class name in Test.aspx.cs is `Test`, i chanced the `caller` to `Test` and I still have the problem

Comment: You probably want to change the class name on the .aspx file itself.  The .designer file will be auto-generated accordingly.